# what are the drawbacks of typecasting a variable to a dataype in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have seen people take some partial object and cast with *as* keyword and pass it to a function that requires a certain type of object as input.

```
someFunctionFoo(bar: barType[]) {
//do something
}

someFunction(items.map((item: Item) => item.name) as argument[]);
```

What are the cons of typecasting this way?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpgAaN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.    Also note that the usual naming convention for custom types is UpperPascalCase not lowerPascalCase, so if you do produce a [mre] it should probably use `BarType` and `Argument`.

Comment: The term "cast" can mean different things (e.g., runtime coercion) so it is best avoided.  TypeScript has [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which only affect compile-time type checking and have no effect on runtime at all.